# Is it possible to dynamically generate <p> in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to dynamically generate `<p>` in ASP.NET code behind (VB)? I've been trying to find an example where `<p>` has been generated using `HtmlGenericControl` like the usual `Dim div As New HtmlGenericControl("DIV")`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
Dim p As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("p")
p.InnerText = "The content goes here"
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(p)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new to VB, and wondered why `Dim div2 As New HtmlGenericControl("DIV")` didn't work.